# putting a react-router application on github gh-pages

Tags: react-router, github-pages

I'm trying to serve my react-router application on github pages (gh-pages) branch.

in the console, I get the error: browser.js:49Warning: [react-router] Location "/meetup-events-p1b/" did not match any routes

I see there is a similar scenario in another topic:
[React Router deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517604/react-router-deep-linking/34517798#34517798)

but in addition, I am having my github subdomain forwarded to a personal domain. if I add a static site generator, then should the application display by pushing only the build folder to gh-pages? would react-router work with the domain forwarding?

Comment: Did u ever solved this?

Comment: @goldylucks no, I do not have a resolution but I think my case is unique because of custom domain forwarding. there is a bootstrapped react application project at https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app   (and if you look at the readme, they have a section on configuration for github gh-pages hosting). you might try that. hope it helps! (my temp workaround is only pushing single page apps, no router to gh-pages or advising viewers to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the build folder for react-router apps) 

Comment: Appreciate the update dude. I'm just using surge now. Highly recommend it. Takes 2 minutes to setup and then 10 seconds to deploy with 20 characters from the terminal. they use subdomains like myApp.surge.sh, so no routing problems :)